# Request to reopen question 722643/76571

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/722643/76571) was closed as a duplicate today. Upon close inspection, it is clearly not a duplicate of [the question indicated](https://superuser.com/q/620484/76571).

The old question concerns finding *and replacing* values. The new question wants to identify words from a list that match text in an Excel cell. The values are not to be replaced, and the original data is expected to remain intact. Solutions to the two problems will be different and not useful for solving the other problem.

I voted to leave open, left a comment explaining why, and it still got closed -- presumably because there were so many comments that mine got pushed into the "See more comments" territory. I voted to reopen as well, but I'm the only one.

So FYI, this should be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reopened the post after three votes it already received from the review process.

Comment: Thanks, @slhck and other voters!